# SVN-add and undo-add, what for?

Tags: svn, version-control, addition

I am new to SVN. SVN-add is here to 'prepare a file to be integrated in SVN', right? But if I want it to effectively be integrated in the version control, I have to commit it (tick the box when I do SVN-commit). So why would I undo-add (if add has no consequences before I validate the file integration after commit)?

Also, could you indicate me some good references for use of SVN?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Where do you "tick the box", you are using some GUI front end? The reference is the SVN Book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added a file and then decided that you made a mistake and you really do not want to add it to SVN. So you undo the add (i.e. revert the change in your working copy) before commit.

Answer (score 2):

I use the next svn command with the file/s name at the end:

```
svn del --keep-local
```

Answer (score 1):

Every operation you make in SVN are made localy, in you workspace.

If you don't want to commit your newly added files, you should "cancel" this addition, to have a clean workspace. This the goal of "Undo add".

Here is a very good lecture about SVN: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Answer (score 0):

> So why would I undo-add (if add has no consequences before I validate
>   the file integration after commit)?

It's true that if you never commit that file you will never see it added to your SVN repository. But instead of thinking 'prepares for integration', think 'places the file under version control'.  What this means is that if you do SVN operations on a folder level rather than a file level, you can be sure only files you deliberately want to update are touched.

If you do **svn up docs/**, and your local folder contains a file with the same name as one in the repository, svn will complain. If your local file was under version control, it could quitely merge the two together instead, without you noticing.

Similarly, if you want to commit a whole folder to the repository, you can be happy that any files not specifically flagged for inclusion (such as **.lck** or **.ds store**) won't be commited by mistake — at best causing unnecessary clutter & at worst causing conflicts between developers on your team.

In this case, not using 'undo-add', would mean that any svn commit at a higher directory level will then add this file to the repository. Probably long after you've forgotten about doing the 'svn add' to begin with :)